# ASP.NET 4.0 on Windows Server 2003 64-bit

Tags: asp.net

Is there a step by step guide on how to enable .NET 4 on IIS 6 running under Windows Server 2003 64bit?

Thank you

Answer (score 12):

1. Install [.NET 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0a391abd-25c1-4fc0-919f-b21f31ab88b7&displaylang=en)
2. Register: `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i`
3. Enable: [image]
4. Have fun <sup>*</sup>

<sup>* This step is not required to make .NET 4.0 run on Windows Server 2003 but it is strongly recommended</sup>